# Paste results of SQL query into specifc cells based on value of other cells

Tags: sql, excel, vba

So in my main sheet of the workbook I have a column containing times, 9:00AM etc. and I use the following code to paste values copied from another workbook into different cells based on what time of day it is:

```vb
lPasteRow = Application.Match(CDbl(Time()), sht_Target.Range("A:A"), 1)
sht_Target.Cells(lPasteRow, 3) = rng_data.Value
```

This works perfectly fine. But only part of my data is pulled from another worksheet. The other half comes from SQL queries. The queries themselves run perfectly and they paste right now into just a single cell for testing purposes. I now need to get them paste into specific cells based on the time of day just like the above code. If the following is my SQL query sub:

```vb
 Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Set sht_Target = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main Sheet")
Dim path As String

Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim Server_Name As String
Dim Database_Name As String
Dim SQLStr As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset



 Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
 Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" &          Database_Name & ""


 rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic

 With sht_Target.Range("Q2")
    .ClearContents
    .CopyFromRecordset rs
 End With

 rs.Close
 Set rs = Nothing
 Cn.Close
 Set Cn = Nothing
```

how would I go about getting this to paste the results into the cells based on the time of day?

Edit: I should probably clarify that all the SQL queries work perfectly and return just a number. Either a total or a percentage. I just need to make sure that if it is 10AM then then results go into Row 3, because A3 says 10:00 AM and so on.

Comment: Please show the SQL query so we can have an idea of its rows and columns.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It's a very simple query.

 SQLStr = "select COUNT(Distinct Agent) from dbo.five9calldataextractdaily WHERE CallDate > CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) and CallType = 'Outbound'"


Even the other ones are just sum over sum queries. The results all work just fine I just need to make sure they go into the corresponding row. So if it's 10AM then I need the results to go into row 3. Cell A3 contains 10:00 AM. Then so on and so on. @parfait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have ADO available, consider running two SQL queries:

1. SQL Server query that dumps to a *Temp Sheet* sheet (created in advance).
2. Excel workbook SQL query that matches *Main Sheet* with *Temp Sheet*.

However, first, adjust aggregate SQL query to add a `GROUP BY` clause where every *CallDate* appears in separate rows, assuming this field is to be matched in Excel:

```sql
SELECT CallDate, COUNT(Distinct Agent) AS AgentCount
FROM dbo.five9calldataextractdaily 
WHERE CallDate > CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND CallType = 'Outbound'
GROUP BY CallDate
```

Then run your ADO connections and, in fact, consider an ADO function since only connection strings and query strings change.

**ADO** Function *(includes parameters for worksheet and copyrecordset range cell)*

```vb
Function ADO_Call(strConn As String, strSQL As String, strWks As String, strCell As String)
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim i As Long

    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set Rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    Cn.Open strConn
    Rs.Open strSQL, Cn, adOpenStatic

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strWks)            
       ' ROWS
       .Range(strCell).CopyFromRecordset Rs

       ' COLUMNS
       If strWks = "TEMP" Then
          For i = 1 To Rs.Fields.Count
              .Cells(1, i) = Rs.Fields(i - 1).Name
          Next i
       End If
    End With

    ThisWorkbook.Save

ExitHandle:
    Rs.Close: Cn.Close
    Set Rs = Nothing: Set Cn = Nothing
    Exit Function

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume ExitHandle
End Function
```

**SQL Server** Connect *(used for temp staging of query results)*

```vb
Sub SQL_Server_Connect()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    Dim Server_Name As String, Database_Name As String
    Dim strConn As String, strSQL As String

    Server_Name = "****"
    Database_Name = "****"    

    strConn = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name

    strSQL = "SELECT CallDate, COUNT(Distinct Agent) AS AgentCount" _
                & " FROM dbo.five9calldataextractdaily " _
                & " WHERE CallDate > CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) " _
                & " AND CallType = 'Outbound' " _
                & " GROUP BY CallDate"

    Call ADO_Call(strConn, strSQL, "TEMP", "A2")

ExitHandle:
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume ExitHandle
End Sub
```

**Excel** Match Connect

```vb
Sub Excel_Match()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    Dim strConn As String, strSQL As String

    strConn = "DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" _
                & "DBQ=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";"

    strSQL = "SELECT t.AgentCount FROM [MAIN$] m " _
              & " LEFT JOIN [TEMP$] t ON m.[CallDate] = t.[CallDate]"

    Call ADO_Call(strConn, strSQL, "MAIN", "Q2")

ExitHandle:
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume ExitHandle
End Sub
```

**Notes**:

- This solution assumes you run Excel for Windows PC machines with access to Jet/ACE SQL Engine (Windows .dll files) with Excel Driver installed (check Odbcad32.exe).
- Excel SQL query depends on named column headers at top of both sheets which are used in joins and select clauses. Hence, why headers are added to *TEMP*. Adjust names as needed.
- `LEFT JOIN` is used instead of `INNER JOIN` to preserve original Excel order and for any unmatched rows which will return with missing *AgentCount* values.

---

**Alternative Solutions**:

1. If Excel query is too complex, simply run the SQL Server query and dump results into a temp worksheet and then use `INDEX(... MATCH(...))` or `VLOOKUP()` to align *CallDates* and retrieve *AgentCount* values.
2. Use a medium between these two, namely MS Access, where you can import Excel sheet and run SQL Server query on [linked table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-or-link-to-data-in-an-sql-server-database-a5a3b4eb-57b9-45a0-b732-77bc6089b84e) to *dbo.five9calldataextractdaily* and then `LEFT JOIN` the two data sources in Access query (btw - same engine as Excel query!).

Comment: Haha...I was expecting some back and forth to clarify. Great to hear and glad to ho help!